# Grabbing a url parameter in php

Tags: php, url, parameters

I have a url like this:

```
    http://ar.com.expedia.www/Mendoza-Hoteles-Mod-Hotels-Mendoza.h3385807.Informacion-Hotel?chkin=01/05/2014&chkout=04/05/2014&rm1=a2&
```

Please notice the & at the end of the url.I need to get this  url from a restful web service.
How can I grab the whole url as a parameter including the trailing ampersand. Ignore the reversed domain. It is taken care of.

I have tried this:

```
    $url = array_shift($_GET);
    foreach ($_GET as $key => $value) {
        $url .= '&' . $key . (($value == '') ? '' : '=') . $value;
    }
```

Comment: can you specify it a little bit more? whats the exactly value you want to extract?

Comment: the entire url from http:// to the last &

Comment: you want this? 
"ar.com.expedia.www/Mendoza-Hoteles-Mod-Hotels-Mendoza.h3385807.Informacion-Hotel?chkin=01/05/2014&chkout=04/05/2014&rm1=a2" including or not including the last &?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by `parse_url` :

```
var_dump(
  parse_url("http://ar.com.expedia.www/Mendoza-Hoteles-Mod-Hotels-Mendoza.h3385807.Informacion-Hotel?chkin=01/05/2014&chkout=04/05/2014&rm1=a2&")
);
```

Result would be as

```
array(4) {
  ["scheme"]=>
  string(4) "http"
  ["host"]=>
  string(18) "ar.com.expedia.www"
  ["path"]=>
  string(62) "/Mendoza-Hoteles-Mod-Hotels-Mendoza.h3385807.Informacion-Hotel"
  ["query"]=>
  string(42) "chkin=01/05/2014&chkout=04/05/2014&rm1=a2&"
}
```

You can then use `explode` for the `["query"]` to move on.

Comment: i thought in using parse_url method but regex was easier

Answer (score 0):

an example using regex
check if its that what you want

```
<?php
$a="http://ar.com.expedia.www/Mendoza-Hoteles-Mod-Hotels-Mendoza.h3385807.Informacion-  Hotel?chkin=01/05/2014&chkout=04/05/2014&rm1=a2&";

preg_match("/(?:http(?:s)?:\/\/)(.+)$/","$a",$result);

echo $result[1];

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here You Go!!!

```
<?php
$url = 'http://www.IrfanAnsari.com/embedviz?q=select+col9+from+1c16ZytvOGsazT5r4borWzDSKmRy1dyeCqzOHdnWb&viz=MAP&h=false&lat=28.098107336734692&lng=68.93999515039059&t=1&z=6&l=col9&y=2&tmplt=2&hml=GEOCODABLE';

function grab_url($url) {
  if(!empty($url)) {
    $urllist=parse_url($url);
    if(is_array($urllist) && isset($urllist["query"])) {
      $keyvalue_list=explode("&",($urllist["query"]));
      $keyvalue_result=array();
      foreach($keyvalue_list as $key=>$value) {
        $keyvalue=explode("=",$value);
        if(count($keyvalue)==2) 
          $keyvalue_result[$keyvalue[0]]=$keyvalue[1];
      }
    }
  }
  return $keyvalue_result;
}
var_dump( grab_url($url) );
?>
```